# Why is this giving me "is a rigid type variable bound by" error

Tags: haskell, types

```
heist :: (Num n) => [n] -> [n] -> n -> n
-- heist [] [] _ = 0
heist w v maxw = func w v i j where
    i = length w
    j = maxw  
func :: (Num n) => [n] -> [n] -> n -> n -> n 
func _ _ 0 0 = 0
```

the above code is giving me:

```
Heist.hs:15:27:
    Could not deduce (n ~ Int)
    from the context (Num n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 heist :: Num n => [n] -> [n] -> n -> n
      at Heist.hs:(15,1)-(17,16)
      `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for heist :: Num n => [n] -> [n] -> n -> n
          at Heist.hs:15:1
    In the third argument of `func', namely `i'
    In the expression: func w v i j
    In an equation for `heist':
        heist w v maxw
          = func w v i j
          where
              i = length w
              j = maxw
```

Why is that happening?

I am wrapping my head around Haskell type system inch by inch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`length` returns an `Int`; use `i = Data.List.genericLength w` or `i = fromIntegral (length w)`.

Comment: hmm, elaborate please?  I thought `Int` is an instance of `Num`, why does it still need that kind of "fromIntegral" conversion?

Comment: The type of `heist` promises "you give me an arbitrary type `n` with `Num n`, I'll give you a function of type `[n] -> [n] -> n -> n`". So suppose we are given some type `n` (the "rigid type variable"), about which we know nothing (except that it is an instance of `Num`). We then call `func` at `n = Int`, which again returns an `Int`. But we were supposed to return a value of the type `n` we were given.

Comment: In short, your type signature promises that `heist` will also work for Double (among others). But it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

`length` always returns an `Int`. By passing `i` to `func` you're saying that `n` should be `Int`, but `heist` wants `n` to be generic, hence the type error.